# Problema com alocamento dinâmico de matrizes bidimencionais em C

Tags: c, array, matriz, alocação

Preciso fazer um produto de matrizes em que o usuário deve inserir as dimensões e os termos das matrizes, porém o programa simplesmente para de funcionar. Segue o código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

int i, j, ja, linhasA, colunasA, linhasB, colunasB; 
float **A;                                              
float **B;
float **C;


printf("Insira o numero de linhas da matriz A:\n");         /* recebe o numero de Linhas de A */
scanf("%i", &linhasA);
printf("Insira o numero de colunas da matriz A:\n");        /* recebe o numero de Colunas de A */
scanf("%i", &colunasA);

A = malloc(linhasA * sizeof(int*));                         /* Aloca A */
    for (i = 0; i < linhasA; ++i)
    {
        A[linhasA] = malloc(colunasA * sizeof(int));
    }

if(A == 0 || A == NULL){                                    /* verifica se foi possivel alocar a memoria desejada */
    printf("Erro: nao foi possível alocar memoria solicitada \n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Insira o numero de linhas da matriz B:\n");         /* recebe o numero de Linhas de B */
scanf("%i", &linhasB);

printf("Insira o numero de colunas da matriz B:\n");        /* recebe o numero de Colunas de B */
scanf("%i", &colunasB);

B = malloc(linhasB * sizeof(int*));                         /* Aloca B */ 
    for (i = 0; i < linhasB; ++i)
    {
        B[linhasB] = malloc(colunasB * sizeof(int));
    }

if(B == 0 || B == NULL){                                    /* verifica se foi possivel alocar a memoria desejada */
    printf("Erro: nao foi possível alocar memoria solicitada \n");
    exit(1);
}

/* Depois de alocados A e B, devemos alocar a matriz que conterá o resultado 
com o numero de linhas de A e o numero de colunas de B  */

C = malloc(linhasA * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < linhasA; ++i)
    {
        C[linhasA] = malloc(colunasB * sizeof(int));
    }

if(C == 0 || C == NULL){                                    /* verifica se foi possivel alocar a memoria desejada */
    printf("Erro: nao foi possível alocar memoria solicitada \n");
    exit(1);
}


if(colunasA == linhasB){                                    /* verifica se a multiplicação é possivel */
    printf("ok!\n");
}
else{
    printf("as matrizes nao possuem uma dimenssao utilizavel\n");
    return 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < linhasA; ++i)                               /* recebe e imprime A */
{
    for (j = 0; j < colunasA; ++j)
    {
        printf("Digite o valor de A[%d][%d]\n", i+1, j+1);
        scanf("%f", &A[i][j]);
    }
}

printf("\n\n");
for (i = 0; i < linhasA; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < colunasA; ++j)
    {
        printf("%f   ", A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

printf("\n\n");

for (i = 0; i < linhasB; ++i)                               /* recebe e imprime B */
{
    for (j = 0; j < colunasB; ++j)
    {
        printf("Digite o valor de B[%d][%d]\n", i+1, j+1);
        scanf("%f", &B[i][j]);
    }
}

printf("\n\n");
for (i = 0; i < linhasB; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < colunasB; ++j)
    {
        printf("%f   ", B[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

printf("\n\n");                                             /* faz a multiplicação */ 

for (i = 0; i < linhasA; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < colunasB; ++j)
    {
        C[i][j] = 0;
        for (ja = 0; ja < colunasA; ja++)
        {
                C[i][j] = C[i][j] + (A[i][ja] * B[ja][j]);
        }
    }
}

printf("\n\n");                                             /* imprime o resultado */

for (i = 0; i < linhasA; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < colunasB; ++j)
    {
        printf("%f  ", C[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

return 0;}
```

Comment: Você já tentou usar um depurador? É mais fácil você conseguir ajuda se nos disser qual é a linha na qual o programa para. Outra coisa: você parece estar complicando muito sua vida tratando as alocações de forma separada e usando ponteiro para ponteiro. Você pode simplesmente alocar `m*n*sizeof(int)` bytes e pode usar ponteiros simples, fazendo a aritmética básica nos seus subscritos.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você quis dizer com `m*n*sizeof(int)`, gostaria de saber se poderia me dar algum exemplo de uso para que eu possa experimenta-lo;

Debuguei o programa e recebi :
`[New Thread 8368.0x257c]
 [New Thread 8368.0x1bb0]

 Breakpoint 4, 0x0040143d in main ()`

Comment: Você pode alocar toda a memória que vai usar sequencialmente, num malloc só. A quantidade de memória necessária é a quantidade de linhas multiplicada pela de colunas multiplicada pelo tamanho do dado.

Comment: e como eu declararia a matriz depois de aloca-la sequencialmente ?

Comment: Você pode usar os operadores de subscrito como açúcar sintático. Fica semelhante ao uso de um vetor de duas dimensões alocado no armazenamento automático mesmo.

Comment: Desculpe, não estou no computador pra te dar um exemplo com certeza é faz tempo que fiz isso, mas é só uma dica de caminho. Seu problema certamente é outro e talvez o que estou falando seja mais complicado pra você entender.

Comment: Entendo, mesmo assim obrigado pela ajuda, pesquisarei mais sobre seu método : ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não está alocando os valores no lugar certo. A linha

```
A[linhasA] = malloc(colunasA * sizeof(int));
```

faz com que todos os valores alocados fiquem na posição `linhasA` assim não existe as posições `[0..n-1]` em seu ponteiro.

Você deve passar para

```
for (i = 0; i < linhasA; ++i){
    A[i] = malloc(colunasA * sizeof(int));
}
```

Assim todas as posições do ponteiro terão um espaço alocado. O mesmo vale para alocar a memória de `B` e `C`.

```
B[linhasB] = malloc(colunasB * sizeof(int));
/*...*/
C[linhasA] = malloc(colunasB * sizeof(int));
```

Devem ficar:

```
B[i] = malloc(colunasB * sizeof(int));
/*...*/
C[i] = malloc(colunasB * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe um erro conceitual aqui: Ponteiros para ponteiros não são matrizes bidimensionais.

Apesar de serem acessadas da mesma maneira utilizando os operador de subscrito `[]`, a forma como a memória foi alocada é diferente.

Uma matriz n-dimensional será sempre alocada em um único bloco de memória enquanto o que você está fazendo é criar uma estrutura de dados composta por vários blocos de memória alocados.

Matrizes, independente da quantidade de dimensões, podem ser copiadas com o operador `=` enquanto estruturas de dados complexas precisam de algoritmos específicos de cópia.

Detalhes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586702/is-2d-array-a-double-pointer